# Can a Kundalini awakened person experience Ramayana, Mahabhrata etc.,

Tags: yoga, time, kundalini

Valmiki got power from Brahma to experience all things in-order to write Ramayana and is explained in Ramayana. The following words of Brahma clarifies it

> "The adventures of valorous Rama along with Lakshmana, and the
> misadventures of demons, known or unknown in every detail, and even
> the plight of Vaidehi which is either revealed or un-revealed so far,
> and whatever legend that has happened, **all that will also be known to
> you**, even if it were to be unknown, as yet...
>
> [[1-2-33-34]](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga2/bala_2_frame.htm)

Similarly Vyasa got power to experience Mahabharata.

My doubt is whether a person **whose Kundalini reached Sahastra** can able to experience Ramayana, Mahabharata, all past events along with all details or not?

Comment: Whether this is opinion based question or not? @hanugm

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I think no because scriptures do comment about it either directly or indirectly.

Comment: There were instances of Yogis of highest order narrating the events of Ramayana as if they had seen.  We have to believe them as no corroborative evidence can be produced for their words.  Shall I quote such incident ?@hanugm

Comment: @srimannarayanakv If they explicitly say that they can see any thing, then okay.

Comment: See the last point on page no. 15 of this book. I haven't found any scripture (yet) that supports the claim, so not writing answer based on that source alone. - https://books.google.co.in/books?id=qKT5ciX9Rg4C&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=can+a+person+with+awakened+kundalini+can+see+past+and+future&source=bl&ots=VTTDYAjA9t&sig=ACfU3U29CdpDGV0nYiZ1JbwXtGm36SURPw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7jPnE5c3lAhXHOo8KHYLTCb8Q6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=can%20a%20person%20with%20awakened%20kundalini%20can%20see%20past%20and%20future&f=false

Answer (score 3):

Yogis of highest order can definitely describe past events.

Sri Krishna says in BG that he taught Yoga to Vivasvata.

> इमं विवस्वते योगं प्रोक्तवानहमव्ययम्।
>
> विवस्वान् मनवे प्राह मनुरिक्ष्वाकवेऽब्रवीत्।।4.1।।
>
> The Bhagavat said This changeless Yoga I had properly taught thus to
>   Vivasvat; Vivasvat correctly told it ot Manu; and Manu declared to
>   Iksvaku.

Then when Arjuna questions as to how Sri Krishna, who took birth in his times, could teach to Vivasvata, Sri Krishna says that ***he knows all the births that passed but Arjuna did not.***

> बहूनि मे व्यतीतानि जन्मानि तव चार्जुन।
>
> तान्यहं वेद सर्वाणि न त्वं वेत्थ परन्तप।।4.5।।
>
> The Bhagavat said O Arjuna, many births of Mine, as well as of yours
>   have passed. All of them I do know, but you do not, O scorcher of foes
>   !

---

Sri Shirdi Sai, a saint of the highest order, assures one of his Devotees Shyama that [he had been a witness to Ramayana.](http://shirdisaisamajusa.blogspot.com/p/madhavrao-deshpande-shyama-introduction.html)

> Shyama asked Sai Baba, "Deva it is written in Ramayana that Lord Rama
>   got a bridge built by 1 crore (10 million) monkeys. This bridge (is
>   called Setu) spanned the sea, so Lord Rama and his troops could cross
>   the sea and reach Lanka. There he waged war with Ravana and vanquished
>   him. Deva, is this true?"
>
> Sai Baba replied, "Yes this is true. The sea is real and Lord Rama was
>   really there."
>
> Shyama inquired, "Deva, where did so many monkeys sit? And how did
>   they sit?
>
> Sai Baba replied, "They sat on the trees and clung to the branches.
>   They looked like myriads of ants."
>
> Then Shyama asked Sai Baba, which perhaps only he could lovingly dare,
>   "Did you see this with your own eyes?"
>
> Sai Baba replied, "Yes, yes I saw them with my own eyes, Shyama."
>
> Shyama again said what only he could lovingly dare, "When I first saw
>   You, You hardly had stubble of mustache (a popular way in India to
>   suggest youngsters). Then how and when did you go to see 'Vanara Sena
>   (troops of monkeys)."
>
> Sai Baba replied, "Shamyaa (as He lovingly called Shama) you and I
>   have been together for many generations. I remember them but you do
>   not."
>
> In wonders Shyama asked, "How old were you then?"
>
> Sai Baba, "Just as you see me now."
>
> Shyama could not grasp the immensity of this spiritual fact or truth.
>   He persisted, "Is this really true?"
>
> Sai Baba as always, "***Have I ever lied sitting here in the Dwarkamai?
>   What I say is true. I swear by you."***

Comment: first line seems attractive :P